# Swift init array from rawValues

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an array of raw values of enum. In one line of Swift code, is it possible to make an array of enum from this raw value array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be even easier.

```
enum Fruit: String {
    case apple = "Apple"
    case banana = "Banana"
}

let rawValues = ["Banana", "Apple", "Apple", "Pig"]
let enums = rawValues.compactMap(Fruit.init)
```

You can simply provide compactMap with the init method, and it will strip away all situations where it was not possible to create a fruit

Comment: This is witchcraft, if I’ve ever seen any.

Answer (score 2):

Use `compactMap`:

```
enum Foo: Int {
    case foo
    case bar
    case baz
}

let foos = [0,1,42].compactMap { Foo(rawValue: $0) } // [foo,bar]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
let array:[Enum] = [String]().map { (rawValue) -> T in return Enum(rawValue: rawValue) }
```